# how get current label's width

Tags: java, swing, width, jlabel

There a panel. I add JLabel on that panel and want to know the size of that JLabel.

Here is simple code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Label;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    MyPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));        
        Label myLabel = new Label("ddddddddd");
        this.add(myLabel);        
        System.out.println(myLabel.getPreferredSize().width);        
        System.out.println(myLabel.getSize().width);
        System.out.println(myLabel.getMinimumSize().width);
        System.out.println(myLabel.getMaximumSize().width);
    }
}


class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    MyFrame() {        
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        this.add(new MyPanel());                
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}


public class Text {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                new MyFrame();                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The results is not what I expected:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
32767.0
```

In some other programm I use the "getPreferredSize().width" and I receive correct result but unfortunately I don't have working code on my hand now.

Can someone explane why with "getPreferredSize().width" I receive zero and how can I get the current label's width?

Comment: 1) Don't mix Swing and AWT components together without good cause.  In this case, use a `JLabel` instead. 2) That code is checking the size of the label before it has been 'realized on-screen', and before the frame has been packed.  Do both these things before querying the size.  3) *"how get current label's width(?)"*  Why do you want that measurement?  In over a decade of developing Swing GUIs, I've needed to query a label for its size exactly (counts carefully) **0 times.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.swing.JLabel` instead `java.awt.Label`

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("ddddddddd");
```

OUTPUT:

```
63
0
63
63
```

Comment: Huh.. I am surprised that changing from `Label` to `JLabel` fixed it!